# Create custom XML in module block

Tags: xml, magento2

I am trying to create custom xml that will have all order related information. I have created one module for that and in that module block I am using following code to generate xml -

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); 
$doc->formatOutput = true; 
$root = $doc->createElementNS('http://www.alshaya.com' ,'co:customerOrders');
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:types', 'http://www.alshaya.com/schema/types/v1.0');
$doc->appendChild($root); 
$customerOrder = $doc->createElement("co:customerOrder");
$root->appendChild(111);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

But I am getting following error and I am unable to generate xml code.

```
**Fatal error**: Class 'DOMDocument' not found
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you check php-dom is installed on your server or not?

Answer (score 0):

try importing it in your namespace:

```
namespace ...
use DOMDocument;
class ...
  { 
  ...
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```